# Getting 'Is inaccessible due to its protection level' error when trying to use MembershipProvider.EncryptPassword

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

```
 public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel RegisterModel, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;

                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                Byte[] Password = encoding.GetBytes(RegisterModel.Password);
                var EncryptedPass = MembershipProvider.EncryptPassword(Password);

                Membership.CreateUser(RegisterModel.UserName, RegisterModel.Password, RegisterModel.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterModel.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                    return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Education"));
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(RegisterModel);
        }
```

Trying to encrypt a password before storing it in the database using the EncryptPassword method and then Dycrypt it with MembershipProvider.DecryptPassword Method but getting a 'Is inaccessible due to its protection level' error warning.

Comment: Need to see more code to tell you what is going on. It has something to do with private or internal members you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both `MembershipProvider.EncryptPassword` and `MembershipProvider.DecryptPassword` method are protected.

So, You will not be able to access them out side the class or its derived class definition.

And while creating any user via `Membership.CreateUser` it automatically encrypt the password.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I probably don't even need to call those from my action methods and the default membership provider likely handles the encypting/decrypting provided the PasswordFormat property is set to "Encrypted" in web.config.